# Retrieving ParseObject ID after saving it in background

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse services for Android. After I create a ParseObject, put some data into it, and then do saveInBackground, is there any way to retrieve the ParseObject ID I just saved into the cloud?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this link, once the user saves in background here the user stores the object id in a string using the keyword getObjectId() function. Hope this helps you.
https://parse.com/questions/how-to-get-the-parse-object-id-after-saving-it-with-saveinbackgroud